# Why are there some users that cannot be clicked on or viewed?

Tags: support

A number of time I've come across users with the same avatar, each of which cannot be viewed by me. It looks like 
 [image: this]

Does this mean the question or user is from a different site? What's the deal?

Answer (score 6):

It means the user does not have an account on EL&U. This can be a user who asked a question on another site, which was then migrated, or a user who had their account deleted.

Comment: Just to note: this does not affect users who have not registered.